# Jenkins return same queue id for diffrent job runs

Tags: rest, jenkins

I'm running jenkins from rest api, and I have a job that doesn't have "Execute concurrent builds if necessary" flag checked (don't want it to be). 
When a build is running and i make another request it gets in the queue, and i get queue id which i later sample to get actual job id when it start running.
The problem is when one build is in queue and i make another request it also goes to queue and get same queue id (its queueitem -> path on the returning json). 
Then when my program try to check job status these two builds are checking the same job id.
Is this known bug?
is there anyway around it?

Comment: Having the same issues. Haven't found an answer yet, did you manage to figure it out eventually?

Comment: Yes, but not via jenkins. I built my own queue mechanism in app, so when the job im trying to run has something in queue(jenkins queue) i save next job in my app queue. Every interval i check to see if i can send next run for the job (i.e if its jenkins queue is empty).